# REST API returning HTML garbage on Standard HTTPWebRequest POST

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, httpwebrequest

I have an Application making a Web Request to get back a data set to display to Users live quotes.  I checked the Web API and not much has changed, my web request seems to be formatted correctly, with the correct request body Payload but I am not getting back the data.

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SearchHelper.SearchUrl);
httpRequest.Method = "POST"; 
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8"; 
httpRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); 
httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetWebRequestBody), httpRequest);
```

Does anyone know what is going on?  I can make a similar request via a browser and I still get back my properly formatted data for my live quotes, however through a .Net HttpWebRequest that has always worked before is now returning the below Content.

> "   Loading site please
>   wait...      html{height: 100%}body{margin: 0;height:
>   100%;}header{background-color: #020202;height: 64px;width:
>   100%;display: none;}header img{margin: 3px 0 0 2px;}section{height:
>   calc(100% - 64px);}.content{padding: 0;position: relative;top:
>   calc(50% - 64px);text-align: center;margin: auto;transform:
>   translateY(-50%);}.left-img{display: inline-block;margin-right:
>   23px;}#JSCookieMSG .left-img, #JSOffMSG .left-img{display:
>   inline-block;margin: 0 23px 0 0;}.right-msg{display:
>   inline-block;color: #4b4b4b;text-align:
>   left;}.msg-head{vertical-align: top;margin: 0;display:
>   inline-block;color: #4b4b4b;font-size: 35px;line-height:
>   33px;font-weight: bold;font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial,
>   sans-serif;padding-top: 46px;}#loading-content{padding:
>   10px;}#loading-content .left-img{margin-right: 10px;height:
>   10px;}#loading-content .left-img img{height: 8px;}#loading-content
>   .msg-head{vertical-align: inherit;color: #4b4b4b;font-size:
>   17px;font-weight: normal;padding-top: 0;line-height:
>   22px;}#JSCookieMSG .msg-head, #JSOffMSG .msg-head{font-size:
>   35px;line-height: 33px;font-weight: bold;font-family: 'Arial Narrow',
>   Arial, sans-serif;}.divider{display: inline-block;margin: 0 21px 0
>   20px;}.msg-head-cookies{margin: 0;}.msg-head-js{margin: 0 0 0
>   2px;}.msg-main{margin-top: 14px;padding: 0;font-size:
>   13px;line-height: 16px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue',
>   Helvetica, sans-serif;}.icon{margin: -4px 9px 0
>   -3px;}.incident-id{display: inline-block;font-size: 15px;vertical-align: top;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue',
>   Helvetica, sans-serif;}@media(max-width: 768px){header img{margin-top:
>   3px;min-width: 400px;width: 100%;max-width: 561px;height:
>   65px;}.content{top: 200px;}}@media(max-width:
>   556px){.left-img{display: none;}.content{top:
>   200px;}}@media(max-height: 580px){.content{top: 200px;}}
>            Loading site please
>   wait...     #loading-content{display: none;}
>        Cookies disabled  This
>   website is using a security service to protect itself from online
>   attacks.
>  The service requires full cookie support in order to view
>   the website.
>  Please enable Cookies on your browser and try again.
>
> Reference ID:
>   ff0bdf6aeb56b1845c11e93b11faecc9          JavaScript Disabled  This
>   website is using a security service to protect itself from online
>   attacks.
>  The service requires full JavaScript support in order to
>   view the website.
>  Please enable Javascript on your browser and try
>   again.   Reference ID:
>   ff0bdf6aeb56b1845c11e93b11faecc9    
>    function
>   sbbloadmid(){if(window.sbrmp){var
>   smbMode=\"frm\";if(smbMode==\"frm\"){var
>   bodyObj=document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0];var
>   submitFrm=document.createElement(\"form\");bodyObj.appendChild(submitFrm);submitFrm.id=\"sbmtfrm\";submitFrm.method=\"post\";submitFrm.action=\"\";submitFrm.sbbSbmt=submitFrm.submit;submitFrm.sbbSbmt();}else
>   window.location.reload(true);}else{setTimeout(\"sbbloadmid()\",
>   50);}}var
>   cookieenabled=false;if(navigator.cookieEnabled){if(navigator.cookieEnabled==true){var
>   exdate=new
>   Date();exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+1);document.cookie=\"sbtsck=jav;path=/;expires=\"+exdate.toGMTString()+\"\";cookieenabled=(document.cookie.indexOf(\"sbtsck\")!=-1)?
>   true :
>   false;}}if(cookieenabled){setTimeout(\"sbbloadmid()\",50);}else{var
>   oJSCookieMSGObj=document.getElementById('JSCookieMSG');var
>   loadingContent=document.getElementById('loading-content');var
>   header=document.getElementsByTagName('header');oJSCookieMSGObj.style.display='block';header.style.display='block';loadingContent.style.display='none';}
>            \n
>   \n            sbbvscc='';\n
>   sbbgscc='';\n            function genPid() {return
>   String.fromCharCode(119)+String.fromCharCode(70) ; };\n
>   \n        \n  (function(XHR){var
>   open=XHR.prototype.open;var send=XHR.prototype.send;var
>   parser=document.createElement('a');XHR.prototype.open=function(method,
>   url, async, user, pass){if(typeof
>   async=='undefined'){async=true;}parser.href=url;if(parser.host==''){parser.href=parser.href;}this.ajax_hostname=parser.hostname;open.call(this,
>   method, url, async, user,
>   pass);};XHR.prototype.send=function(data){if(location.hostname==this.ajax_hostname)this.setRequestHeader(\"X-MOD-SBB-CTYPE\",
>   \"xhr\");send.call(this, data);}})(XMLHttpRequest);function
>   sbbgc(check_name){var
>   start=document.cookie.indexOf(check_name+\"=\");var oVal='';var
>   len=start+check_name.length+1;if((!start)&&(document.cookie.substring(0,check_name.length)!=check_name)){oVal='';}else
>   if(start==-1){oVal='';}else{var
>   end=document.cookie.indexOf(';',len);if(end==-1)end=document.cookie.length;var
>   oVal=document.cookie.substring(len,end);};return oVal;}function
>   addmg(inm,ext){var
>   primgobj=document.createElement('IMG');primgobj.src=window.location.protocol+\"//\"+window.location.hostname+(window.location.port
>   && window.location.port!=80 ? ':'+window.location.port:
>   '')+\"/sbbi/?sbbpg=\"+inm+(ext?\"&\"+ext:\"\");var
>   sbbDiv=document.getElementById('sbbfrcc');sbbDiv.appendChild(primgobj);};function
>   addprid(prid){var
>   oldVal=sbbgc(\"PRLST\");if((oldVal.indexOf(prid)==-1)&&(oldVal.split('/').length<5)){if(oldVal!='')oldVal+='/';document.cookie='PRLST='+oldVal+escape(prid)+';path=/';}}var
>   sbbeccf=function(){this.sp3=\"jass\";this.sf1=function(vd){return
>   sf2(vd)+32;};var sf2=function(avd){return
>   avd*12;};this.sf4=function(yavd){return yavd+2;};var
>   strrp=function(str, key, value){if(str.indexOf('&'+key+'=')> -1 ||
>   str.indexOf(key+'=')==0){var
>   idx=str.indexOf('&'+key+'=');if(idx==-1)idx=str.indexOf(key+'=');var
>   end=str.indexOf('&', idx+1);var newstr;if(end
>   !=-1)newstr=str.substr(0, idx)+str.substr(end+(idx ? 0 :
>   1))+'&'+key+'='+value;else newstr=str.substr(0,
>   idx)+'&'+key+'='+value;return newstr;}else return
>   str+'&'+key+'='+value;};var strgt=function(name, text){if(typeof text
>   !='string')return \"\";var nameEQ=name+\"=\";var
>   ca=text.split(/[;&]/);for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++){var
>   c=ca[i];while(c.charAt(0)==' ')c=c.substring(1,
>   c.length);if(c.indexOf(nameEQ)==0)return c.substring(nameEQ.length,
>   c.length);}return \"\";};this.sfecud={f:function(name, value){var
>   fv=\"\";try{var
>   elm=document.getElementById('sbbfrcc');elm.style.behavior=\"url(#default#userData)\";if(typeof(value)!=\"undefined\"){elm.setAttribute(name,
>   value);elm.save(name);}else{elm.load(name);fv=elm.getAttribute(name);}}catch(e){}return
>   fv;}, name:\"sbbrf\"};this.sfecgs={sbbgh:function(){var
>   domain=document.location.host;if(domain.indexOf('www.')==0)domain=domain.replace('www.',
>   '');return domain;}, f:function(name, value){var
>   fv=\"\";if(window.globalStorage){var
>   host=this.sbbgh();try{if(typeof(value)!=\"undefined\")globalStorage[host][name]=value;else{fv=globalStorage[host][name];if(typeof(fv.toString)!=\"undefined\")fv=fv.toString();}}catch(e){}}return
>   fv;}, name:\"sbbrf\"};this.sfecls={f:function(name, value){var
>   fv=\"\";try{if(window.localStorage){if(typeof(value)!=\"undefined\")localStorage.setItem(name,
>   value);else{fv=localStorage.getItem(name);if(typeof(fv.toString)!=\"undefined\")fv=fv.toString();}}}catch(e){}return
>   fv;}, name:\"sbbrf\"};this.sbbcv=function(invl){try{var
>   invalArr=invl.split(\"-\");if(invalArr.length>1){if(invalArr[0]==\"A\"||invalArr[0]==\"D\"){invl=invalArr[1];}else
>   invl=\"\";}if(invl==null||typeof(invl)==\"undefined\"||invl==\"falseImgUT\"||invl==\"undefined\"||invl==\"null\"||invl!=encodeURI(invl))invl=\"\";if(typeof(invl).toLowerCase()==\"string\")if(invl.length>20)if(invl.substr(0,2)!=\"h4\")invl=\"\";}catch(ex){invl=\"\";}return invl;};this.sbbsv=function(fv){for(var elm in
>   this){if(this[elm].name==\"sbbrf\"){this[elm].f(\"altutgv2\",fv);}}document.cookie=\"UTGv2=\"+fv+';expires=Tue,
>   31 Dec 2030 00:00:00 UTC;path=/';};this.sbbgv=function(){var
>   valArr=Array();var currVal=\"\";for(var elm in
>   this){if(this[elm].name==\"sbbrf\"){currVal=this[elm].f(\"altutgv2\");currVal=this.sbbcv(currVal);if(currVal!=\"\")valArr[currVal]=(typeof(valArr[currVal])!=\"undefined\"?valArr[currVal]+1:1);}}var
>   lb=0;var fv=\"\";for(var val in
>   valArr){if(valArr[val]>lb){fv=val;lb=valArr[val]}}if(fv==\"\")fv=sbbgc(\"UTGv2\");fv=this.sbbcv(fv);if(fv!=\"\")this.sbbsv(fv);else
>   this.sbbsv(\"D-h470427f615e9a3c2e0e8cb93383234e8d86\");return
>   fv;};};function m2vr(m1,m2){var i=0;var rc=\"\";var
>   est=\"ghijklmnopqrstuvwyz\";var rnum;var rpl;var
>   charm1=m1.charAt(i);var
>   charm2=m2.charAt(i);while(charm1!=\"\"||charm2!=\"\"){rnum=Math.floor(Math.random()*
>   est.length);rpl=est.substring(rnum,rnum+1);rc+=(charm1==\"\"?rpl:charm1)+(charm2==\"\"?rpl:charm2);i++;charm1=m1.charAt(i);charm2=m2.charAt(i);}return rc;}function sbbls(prid){try{var eut=sbbgc(\"UTGv2\");sbbeccfi=new
>   sbbeccf();sbbgs=sbbeccfi.sbbgv();if(eut!=sbbgs && sbbgs!=\"\" &&
>   typeof(sbbfcr)==\"undefined\"){addmg('utMedia',\"vii=\"+m2vr(\"15e90d11d95bce15d7faa0030fd4a92d\",sbbgs));}var
>   sbbiframeObj=document.createElement('IFRAME');var dfx=new
>   Date();sbbiframeObj.id='SBBCrossIframe';sbbiframeObj.style.border='0px';if(document.all){sbbiframeObj.style.position='absolute';sbbiframeObj.style.top='-1px';sbbiframeObj.style.height='1px';sbbiframeObj.style.width='28px';}else{sbbiframeObj.style.height='1px';sbbiframeObj.style.width='0px';}sbbiframeObj.scrolling=\"NO\";sbbiframeObj.src=window.location.protocol+\"//\"+window.location.hostname+(window.location.port
>   && window.location.port!=80 ? ':'+window.location.port:
>   '')+'/sbbi/?sbbpg=sbbShell&gprid='+prid +
>   '&sbbgs='+sbbgs+'&ddl='+(Math.round(dfx.getTime()/1000)-1490112137)+'';var
>   sbbDiv=document.getElementById('sbbfrcc');sbbDiv.appendChild(sbbiframeObj);}catch(ex){;}}try{y=unescape(sbbvscc.replace(/^<\!\-\-\s*|\s*\-\->$/g,''));document.getElementById('sbbhscc').innerHTML=y;x=unescape(sbbgscc.replace(/^<\!\-\-\s*|\s*\-\->$/g,''));}catch(e){x='function
>   genPid(){return
>   \"jser\";}';}try{if(window.gprid==undefined)document.write('<'+'script
>   type=\"text/javascri'+'pt\">'+x+\"var
>   gprid=genPid();addprid(gprid);sbbls(gprid);<\"+\"/script>\");}catch(e){addprid(\"dwer\");}
>      "

Comment: Read the content that has been returned: `This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.
The service requires full cookie support in order to view the website.
Please enable Cookies on your browser and try again.`

Comment: I didn't figure it out as such, it's literally written in the response. Use CTRL + F and you'll see it. Yes, I assume you need a cookie container. Without seeing code I don't know which one but your guess looks right to me.

Comment: FYI it also says `JavaScript Disabled This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.
The service requires full JavaScript support in order to view the website.
Please enable Javascript on your browser and try again.`. Don't know how you'd get around that one. Might be time to speak to the provider.

Comment: I see, I did not see that before.             Here is the text:             Cookies disabled This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.
The service requires full cookie support in order to view the website.
Please enable Cookies on your browser and try again.

Reference ID: ff0bdf6aeb56b1845c11e93b11faecc9 JavaScript Disabled This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.
The service requires full JavaScript support in order to view the website.
Please enable Javascript on your browser and try again.

Comment: I'm taking a guess that this is not an API but you're trying to parse a normal HTML page. It looks like they've implemented detection to prevent scrapers from reading the page and they're unfortunately quite effective. Am I right?

Comment: Normally I call it with my POST method and correct Request Body with the search parameters, but I think they recently added some security as you mention because my requests are coming back junk, would you know of anyway around this, or to make the C# HttpWebRequest appear more like a browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is to provide a UserAgent when making the request.

```
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
var result = wc.DownloadString(new Uri("url"));
```

Result now contains the expected JSON

---

OP has clarified that he uses `HttpWebRequest`. Existing code would remain the same, just add this line with an appropriate UserAgent string:

```
httpRequest.UserAgent = 
    "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
```

Quick example (could be improved, just to prove a point):

```
var httpRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("url"); 
httpRequest.Method = "POST"; 
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"; 
httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
var result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Result is the same as above.

Comment: No problem. You can also pass the search parameters as well but since there was no code in your question I can't tell what you're using to make these requests if it's not WebClient.

Comment: Ok taking a look now.

Comment: HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SearchHelper.SearchUrl);
                httpRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    httpRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    
                httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetWebRequestBody), httpRequest);

Comment: I'd recommend editing code into your question with the proper formatting, it's hard to read and may be missed by others readers if left in the comments.

Comment: Added an example for `HttpWebRequest`, works for me. Not sure how this is a security risk, can't see anywhere that you've provided private details and this appears to be a public API. Up to you I guess.

Comment: That UserAgent property is not exposed in Cross Platform Library .Net version for Xamarin which is where this is taking place, trying to find a solution now.  Also you cant set that header directly because it throws an exception because it is on the list of header values you cannot set.

Comment: With 3K+ rep you should know to provide details like that in the question! This works in standard .NET, I'm unfortunately not familiar with the other flavours such as Core etc...

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, I was able to achieve this in Xamarin Forms by adding the System.Net.Http Nuget package.  This package contains the HttpClient class and can be used Cross Platform!